# Plotly choropleth not displaying regions properly

Tags: python, plotly, geojson, choropleth, plotly-express

I am trying to use plotly to display a chropleth map of Spain.

This is the code of my attempt:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd

geo_df = gpd.read_file("cc_aa.geojson") # Read geojson file with geopandas
geo_df=geo_df[geo_df["acom_code"]!="20"] # Filter region that is not needed

region_names =["MELILLA", "MADRID", "CATALUNA", "CEUTA ", "ANDALUCIA", "ISLAS BALEARES",
                      "ISLAS CANARIAS", "EXTREMADURA", "REGION DE MURCIA", "COMUNIDAD VALENCIANA",
                      "LA RIOJA", "CASTILLA Y LEON", "ARAGON", "GALICIA", "COMUNIDAD FORAL DE NAVARRA",
                      "PRINCIPADO DE ASTURIAS", "CASTILLA-LA MANCHA", "CANTABRIA",
                      "PAIS VASCO"]
geo_df["acom_name"]= region_names # rename region names
df = pd.DataFrame([(r,) for r in region_names], columns = ["acom_name"]) # Create a pandas dataframe with the regions
np.random.seed(1)                                   
df["random"] = np.random.rand(19) # Add a random column which will be used in the chropleth map to set the color
print(len(df)) #19
geo_df = geo_df.merge(df, on="acom_name").set_index("acom_name") # merge the geopandas df with the pandas df
print(len(geo_df)) # 19
fig = px.choropleth(geo_df,
                   geojson=geo_df.geometry,color = "random",
                   locations=geo_df.index)
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="geojson", visible=True)
fig.write_html("testing_map.html")
```

This is what the figure looks like:[image]
Only one region (PAIS VASCO) is correctly plotted, which is the last row of the dataframe coincidentally. I can hover over the other regions and I can see the region name and their values though.

The geojson data should be correct, as I can make the plot with geopandas directly with no problems. This is the code:

```
  fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
  geo_df.plot(column='random',ax=ax, legend=True)
```

And the resulting figure:
[image]

The geojson was downloaded from [opendatasoft](https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/georef-spain-comunidad-autonoma/export/?disjunctive.acom_code&disjunctive.acom_name).

Comment: Your question is not clear about the contents of the geojson, so I ran your code using the geojson file here and it displayed correctly. Can you publish the geojson file to make it available?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to upload the file. I have edited the question with the link from where I downloaded the geojson. Which file did you use?

Comment: I have checked using geojson [here](https://github.com/codeforgermany/click_that_hood/blob/main/public/data/spain-provinces.geojson).

Comment: I see, so there was actually something wrong with my data because I have downloaded the equivalent geojson from your link and it displayed correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem there was something wrong with the geojson I was using before (I did not think that to be the case because plotting with geopandas worked correctly).

This is how the plot with the dataset downloaded from [here](https://github.com/codeforgermany/click_that_hood/blob/main/public/data/spain-communities.geojson) looks like:

[image]